# C# Button to view folder just created

Tags: c#, winforms

So in my application I have created, there is a button that will create a folder in a user-selected location, I want to add another button to my application that when clicked, will pull up this folder that has just been created.

I have looked into using Process.Start($@"C:\Users}); but have no way of using the folder path as it has not been created before starting the application. How would I get around this?

Comment: If you create the folder, you should know the path at runtime, allowing you to `Process.Start(your_path_variable_here)`.

Comment: When the user specifies the location to create the folder, save this value in a field https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields, then as @Filburt says, use Process.Start and then the `field` you created will open the File Explorer at that path once the user clicks the other button.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of your code (as text, no screenshots, please) to illustrate your current solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"Path of the folder that you want to open");
```

Just make sure the user by which you are running the application must have access to the folder. Otherwise, you might get issues related to access control.